# How to get first 4 digits in a number, with oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I could do

```
select substr(to_char(20041111), 1, 4) FROM dual;

2004
```

Is there a way without converting to string first?

Comment: `select substr(20041111, 1, 4) from dual;` works as well.

Comment: If it's always 8 digits and it's stored as an INT then you could just divide by 10000

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit oh yeah. I assume it converts to string/chars under the bonnet ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky So that solve the problem? Because dont see what is the issue here?

Comment: @JNevill Oracle database doesn't have an INT datatype.

Comment: @TonyAndrews That would explain why you are suggesting `Floor()` and why sqlfiddle hates my `CREATE TABLE` statement. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @TonyAndrews . . . Well, Oracle does.  To quote the documentation "SQL statements that create tables and clusters can also use ANSI datatypes and datatype".  `INT` and `INTEGER` are equivalent to `NUMBER(38)` and accepted in `CREATE TABLE` statements (for instance).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh yes, so it does - I forgot.  But you still can't do integer arithmetic: `create table t4 (i int); insert into t4 values (20041111);  select i/10000 from t4;` and you get 2004.1111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [FLOOR function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions076.htm#SQLRF00643):

```
select floor(20041111/10000) from dual;
```

Comment: Is floor needed? (Many dbms products return an integer here.)

Comment: Yes, it is needed, otherwise you get 2004.1111

Comment: This is useful as long as you are 100% sure that the total number of digits in the column is the same for all the rows. The solution proposed in the comments, "select substr(20041111, 1, 4)", seems more robust to me... Although I suspect that it implicitly converts to char and then back to number (does it?)

Comment: @Giuseppe you are right.  I think I probably assumed from the example that these "numbers" are really formatted dates - 20141111 meaning 11th November 2014.  But it was a while ago :-)

Answer (score 3):

The following does not convert to a string but I'm not sure it's more readable...:

```
select floor(20041111 / power(10, floor(log(10, 20041111) - 3)))
from dual;
```

log(10, 20041111) -> 8.3... meaning that 10 ^ 8.3... = 20041111

if you floor this value, you get the number of digits in the base 10 representation of your number

if you want to remove digits, you just need to divide by 10 ^ (#digits - 3) (and not -4 since 10^1 already has 2 digits)

Comment: I know what you did. But a litle explanation for the rest would be nice.

Comment: Works great until you put in a three-digit number at which point it right-pads with zeros - which may not be the desired result. That would be up to the OP to define the rules for. If you want to avoid right-padding, (get the first four digits or less if number < 1000) then: floor(:x / power(10, greatest(floor(log(10, :x) - 3),0)))

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `REGEXP_REPLACE`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(20041111,'....$') FROM dual;
```